# Is there a way to pass lambda expression as a predicate template argument?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, lambda, c++14

Is there a way to make this code compile? I want to have my compare function as a lambda template argument.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

int main() 
{
    std::set<int*, [](int *a, int *b){return *a<*b;}> S;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following errors:

```
prog.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
prog.cpp:6:17: error: lambda-expression in template-argument
  std::set<int*, [](int *a, int *b){return *a<*b;}> S;
                 ^
prog.cpp:6:51: error: template argument 2 is invalid
  std::set<int*, [](int *a, int *b){return *a<*b;}> S;
```

Can anyone please help me to correct the code, or explain why its not possible?

Comment: Why is writing `struct name{auto operator()(int *a, int *b){return *a < *b;}};` such an onerous burden?

Comment: @NicolBolas, Its not. I just want to know what I can and what I cant do with the language I use.

Comment: @NicolBolas I believe, you are asking rather moot question. It is not a burden, but if it can be avoided - why not?

Comment: @SergeyA: Because giving the comparison a proper name is more self-documenting than having to read through a lambda to find out what the comparison is doing. Because it makes the `set`'s type shorter and more digestible, both when writing it and in compiler error messages. Because that's simply not what lambdas are for. There are many reasons "why not"; the only reason "why" is that it's shorter... *slightly*.

Comment: @NicolBolas are you advocating against lambas in general? This argument could be applied to any lambda usage.

Comment: @SergeyA: No, this is an argument against using a lambda expression to generate a *type*, rather than using a lambda expression to generate a callable value. The latter is what lambdas are for; the former is not. Yes, lambdas generate types, but that's an implementation detail, not their purpose. `set` takes a type, not a value.

Comment: @NicolBolas, so if, for example, instead of taking a type as a template argument, `set` would take (say, polymorphic callable) callable comparator as a constructor argument you would have no issue with using lambda there (pretty similar to what accepted answer shows)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code is not valid because:

```
[](int *a, int *b){return *a<*b;}
```

...is not a type, it's an object (of implementation-defined type), so you cannot use it as a template parameter.

You could first create the object and then find its type using `decltype`:

```
auto comp = [](int *a, int *b){ return *a<*b; };
std::set<int*, decltype(comp)> S{comp};
```

Or in C++20, you can directly apply the `decltype`:

```
std::set<int*, decltype([](int *a, int *b){return *a<*b;})> S;
```

---

Since your lambda is capture-less, another way is to use a function-pointer type for the comparator type and let the compiler convert the capture-less lambda to a function-pointer:

```
std::set<int*, bool (*)(int*, int*)> S([](int *a, int *b){ return *a<*b; });
```

Answer (score 1):

Answered now, but here is another option if you want to be able to write 
your comparator inline and not specify the type..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

template <typename ,typename>
struct swap_set_comparator{};

template <typename new_comp,typename set_type,typename comp,typename alloc>
struct swap_set_comparator<new_comp,std::set<set_type,comp,alloc> >
{
    using type = std::set<set_type,new_comp,alloc>;
};

template <typename container, typename... Args,typename Func>
auto make_set(Args&&... args,Func&& f)
{
   return typename swap_set_comparator<Func,container>::type(std::forward<Args>(args)...,std::forward<Func>(f));
}


int main() 
{
    // as already answered..

    auto comparator = [](int *a, int *b){return *a<*b;};
    std::set<int*,decltype(comparator)> S(comparator);

    // or 

    auto S2 = make_set<std::set<int*>>([](int *a, int *b){return *a<*b;});
    return 0;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/wcbcXe)